# JavaScript onclick event for game is not working

Tags: javascript, onclick

I am making a game and running into problems with the `onclick` event and others such as `onmouseover`, etc. I am trying to make an `onclick` event that will change the gravity on the canvas from `0` to `0.9` and the error I am getting is:

> `canvas-template.html:45 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onclick' of null at canvasApp (canvas-template.html:45) at onload (canvas-template.html:8)`

Here is my code:

```
//Sets our starting gravity and friction value.
var gravity = 0;
var friction = 0;
// This is the button and onclick event and function
var btn = document.getElementById('btn').onclick(function apple(){
    gravity = 0.9;
    friction = 0.9;
});
```

Also, I have tried this many other ways. This code may not look right, but trust me, I've done it exactly how you would do an `onclick` event and in different projects and for some reason always get these errors.

Comment: I fixed 1 error now the only error is " cannot read property onclick of null"

Comment: the error is telling you it cannot find the element with id="btn". If you can provide a fully formed code sample it would help us debug your code.

Comment: Can you show us the relevant html?

Comment: You're actually calling `onclick` of the element and pass your handler to it. Do it like `.onclick = function apple () {...}`. And move your script at the end of the body element to execute it after all the elements exist.

Comment: It seems to work fine now. thankss (:

Comment: i made a mistake in the button were there was a typo and also my code was alittle wrong. thanks everyone for th help(:

Comment: I would also suggest that `onclick` you call a function that will serve as a modifier for the `gravity` and `friction`. I can easily see this code escalating to manage much more than just those two values; you will most likely be modifying class properties down the line and in that case you will be interacting with setters and getters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must try to change your code like below :

```
//Sets our starting gravity and friction value.
var gravity = 0;
var friction = 0;

// This is the button and onclick event and function
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
btn.onclick(function apple(){
  gravity = 0.9;
  friction = 0.9;
});
```

I hope it can help you or you can try to check here.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp